# compute r(t) in Vasiceck model, what is $e^{at}r$

Tags: fixed-income, interest-rates, vasicek

[image]
I know how to solve the exercise using the hint. But I do not understand where the hint is coming from. Is it just continous compounding?

**Can anybody explain $f(t,r) = e^{at}r$?**
What does it stand for and where does it come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$e^{at}$ is simply the [Integrating factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor) since it reduces the problem to a differential for $f(t,r)$ which is easy to solve. The $a$ comes from the coefficient in front of $r(t)$ in your equation.